# how do I get rid of leading/trailing spaces in SAS search terms?

Tags: excel, sas

I have had to look up hundreds (if not thousands) of free-text answers on google, making notes in Excel along the way and inserting SAS-code around the answers as a last step.

The output looks like this:

[image]

This output contains an unnecessary number of blank spaces, which seems to confuse SAS's search to the point where the observations can't be properly located.

It works if I manually erase superflous spaces, but that will probably take hours. Is there an automated fix for this, either in SAS or in excel?

I tried using the STRIP-function, to no avail:

```
else if R_res_ort_txt=strip("   arild   ") and R_kom_lan=strip("    skåne   ") then R_kommun=strip("    Höganäs " );
```

Comment: Show more of the coding behind *inserting SAS-code around*. The apparent white space is most likely a non-space such as a tab ('09'x) or non-breaking space ('A0`x), or the `=` is not the correct matching operator for SAS (try `FIND`).

Comment: In the excerpt from excel there are exactly three columns of actual data (so "Blacksta", "Södermanland" and "Flen" in the fourth row). The rest of the material is inserted SAS-code

Comment: So before the first column we insert "else if R_res_ort_txt=' ", between the first and the second we insert " ' and R_kom_lan=' " and at the end of the third column we insert " ' ;"

Comment: What is the real goal here?  Show your input data and clearly state how you want to use it.  What is the resulting data you want to get?

Comment: It does not make any sense to have those columns of constant text.  What is the code you used to generate the line of SAS code you showed as actual text (as opposed to the photograph you posted of your dataset)?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to generate a string like:

```
 if R_res_ort_txt="arild" and R_kom_lan="skåne" then R_kommun="Höganäs";
```

from three variables, let's call them A B C, then just use code like:

```
 string=catx(' ','if R_res_ort_txt=',quote(trim(A))
                ,'and R_kom_lan=',quote(trim(B))
                ,'then R_kommun=',quote(trim(C)),';') ;
```

Or if you are just writing that string to a file just use this PUT statement syntax.

```
 put 'if R_res_ort_txt=' A :$quote. 'and R_kom_lan=' B :$quote.
     'then R_kommun=' C :$quote. ';' ;
```

Answer (score 0):

A saner solution would be to continue using the free-text answers as data and perform your matching criteria for transformations with a left join.

```
proc import out=answers datafile='my-free-text-answers.xlsx';

data have;
  attrib R_res_ort_txt R_kom_lan length=$100;
  input R_res_ort_txt ...;
  datalines4; 
  ... whatever all those transforms will be performed on...
;;;;

proc sql;
  create table want as
  select 
    have.* ,
    answers.R_kommun_answer as R_kommun
  from 
    have
  left join 
    answers
  on 
    have.R_res_ort_txt = answers.res_ort_answer
  & have.R_kom_lan     = abswers.kom_lan_answer
  ;
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by adding quotes in excel using the flash fill function:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nE65QeDoepc